# How to setup SQL Server on VMWare for best performance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, vmware

We have Dell r940 server with 64 CPUs.

Processor Type: Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8253 CPU @ 2.20GHz 4 Sockets + 16 Cores per Socket and 128 Logical processors Memory 767 GB

We set the server up on a VMWare v7.0 hypervisor. One of the virtual machines runs Sql Server 2019 Enterprise Edition on Windows 2019 Standard where we have mission-critical workloads.

Can anyone suggest a virtual CPU (Cores per Socket) + RAM configuration for best performance from this machine?